# html5 picture tag, button in the middle of image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to overlay a button on a picture tag like this:

```
<div class="bookList">
    <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="
                /myimage.jpg 1x,
                /myimage-hd.jpg 2x">
        <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="
                /myimage-sd.jpg 1x,
                /myimage-sd.jpg 2x">
        <img srcset="/myimage-low.jpg 1x" alt="my image">

    </picture>
    <a href="/books">
        <button class="btn btn-custom">SOME IMPORTANT TEXT</button>
    </a>
</div>

.bookList {
    width: 100%;
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    a {
            position: relative;
            max-width:100%;

    }
}
.btn-custom{
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

but can't get it on the image, is staying below it.
Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to add the button? Can't you just add an onclick event on your picture element?

Comment: @sorix cuz i have some important text in the button. i want to click only the button which holds the text

Comment: Where do you need your button to be displayed on the picture? In the center, top left, top right, etc ?

Comment: @Sorix slightly below the center, like some small percentage below the center

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using valid css. If you want to refer to an `img` inside of `.bookList` you need to reference it like this: `.bookList img { ...}`. Same for your `a` tag. Unless you are using some CSS compiler you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan sorry, yeah, i am using css compiler

Comment: @moaningalways can you add that as a tag, then? Just to make sure everyone is on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your button into a container and absolute position this container:

```
<div class="bookList">
    <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="
            /myimage.jpg 1x,
            /myimage-hd.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="
            /myimage-sd.jpg 1x,
            /myimage-sd.jpg 2x">
    <img srcset="/myimage-low.jpg 1x" alt="my image">

    </picture>
    <div class="bttn_container">
        <a href="/books">
            <button class="btn btn-custom">SOME IMPORTANT TEXT</button>
        </a>
    </div>

</div> 

.bookList {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 35%;

}

picture{
    position: relative;
}


.bttn_container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-custom{
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: this kind of works, but the button is placed at the top of my page.... whereas this element is somewhere at the bottom of the page...

Comment: i mean `<div class="bookList">` is somewhere in the bottom of the page, and it contains and image, the button should be placed on the image, but it is placed out side of this div and somewhere at the top of the page, using your code.

Comment: I have added the entire CSS (your original code was placing img and a elements inside the bookList style). Also, position: relative; is necessary on .bookList. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use `display: grid`. It is pretty straight forward, responsive, and is supported by most major browsers, I believe.

HTML

```
<div class="bookList">
  <img srcset="https://ulmhawkeyeonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/puppy-development-300x200.jpg 1x" alt="my image">
  <button class="btn btn-custom">SOME IMPORTANT TEXT</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bookList {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

img {
  grid-column: 1 /4;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-custom{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  color:#fff;
  border-color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

RESULT

[image: Results]
I took some liberties with the picture since I didn't know what you were using. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the positioning of the anchor tag to absolute and position it how you wish, like so:

```css
a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
position:relative;
}
img{
width:100%;
height:300px;
}
button{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:none;
 height:30px;
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>HI</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg">
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see the example:

```html
<a href="https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG">click here to this link</a>
```